# Is it wrong to delete a downvoted question?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

As a relatively new user each point I gain or lose seems kind of huge to me. I am aware people may downvote my question if they think it's not specific or relevant and such. Also I noticed that if I delete the downvoted question itself I will not lose any points. If the question was downvoted without any comment specifying the reason or how I can improve the question, then even though it's not mentioned directly in the rules, it is OK if I delete a question just so that I do not lose points?

Comment: You can.  However it won't help you avoid a question ban.  Better to figure out what is wrong with it and fix it.

Comment: I thought people came here to get good answers to their questions, not to gain imaginary Internet points.

Comment: Yep but I believe its essential to reach a bare minimum points that will let me comment or ask doubts to my peers or vote. Its uncomfortable to make a new question when I just need further clarification on previously answered question

Comment: @hunters30 Well if you delete too many questions that are negatively voted, you will be banned from asking questions altogether. Better, as Becuzz pointed out, to make your questions not deserving of a DV in the first place.

Comment: @Patrice ok thats what I wanted to know. So deleting the question for this reason can have a negative impact. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @hunters30 well whenever you go to ask a new question, the system checks if you're "eligible" to asking again. The specifics are not known, but it is known that downvoted questions count against that, and that DELETED downvoted questions count even MORE against that